# concat string in dynamic field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, where partial functionality is completed. 
but what I need to do next is to concat all the fields that the user input in this form.

```js
     
      function addRow(tableID) {
    
       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    
       var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
       var element1 = document.createElement("input");
       element1.type = "checkbox";
       element1.name="chkbox[]";
       cell1.appendChild(element1);
    
       var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
       cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
    
       var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
       var element2 = document.createElement("input");
       element2.type = "text";
       element2.name = "txtbox[]";
       cell3.appendChild(element2);
      }
    
      function deleteRow(tableID) {
       try {
       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    
       for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
         table.deleteRow(i);
         rowCount--;
         i--;
        }
       }
       }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
       }
      }
```

```html
 
    
     <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    
     <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
     
     
     <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
      <TR>
       <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
       <TD> 1 </TD>
       <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
      </TR>
     </TABLE>
```

-> for example if the user click on add row 4 times, the form will create 4 rows now while he click some button (to be made) the result should be concatenation of all the inputs in one large text area. 
thank you in advance

Comment: Great, so start implementing it and let us know if you have any _specific_ questions ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i am trying to concatenate  these dynamic feild's but want to know how to read them into a variable i cannot reference it by id as i dont have them, i can try on name but i need  some hint how to fetch 2 rows data then i can do it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I have created the snippet and read values from input and displayed as json object in textarea on button click event.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.name="chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element2);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }
      }
      updaterowCount();
  }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

function updaterowCount(){
   var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var cell=row.cells[1];
        cell.innerHTML=i+1;
       
    }
}

function getValue(){
var table=document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var data={};
   for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
       var row=table.rows[i];
       var element=row.cells[2].childNodes[0];
       data[i]=element.value;
   }
   document.getElementById("result").value = JSON.stringify(data);

  // console.log(data);
}
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

textarea{
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />


<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td><input type="text" txtbox[]></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="getValue()"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="result" col="100" row="4"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks !! it worked like a charm. love this community